# Closed-form of a series relating to trigonometric function

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

Occasionally, we may meet some huge expressions, see
$$
F(a)=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sin^2\big(\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2N}\big)}{\Big[a^2-2a\cos \big(\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2N}\big)+1\Big]^2}
$$
where $a$ is a real number for instance. For simplicity we can assume that $\vert a\vert<1$. I just wonder that if a closed form exits or not, and what is it.

&**&

My thoughts. To begin with, I try to find the generating function of $F(a)$, but it does not work at all. Afterwards, I find some identities in the book [table of integrals series and products](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123736374), which read
[image]
I hope that them will work. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Considering let $z=ae^{it}$, we have

$$\cos t=\frac{z}{2a}+\frac{a}{2z}$$
$$\sin t=\frac{z}{2a}-\frac{a}{2z}$$

$$\frac{\sin t}{a^{2}-2a\cos t+1}=
\frac{\frac{z}{2a}-\frac{a}{2z} }{|z-1|^{2}}=
\frac{\frac{z}{a}-\frac{a}{z}}{2(z-1)\left( \frac{a}{z}-1 \right)}$$